# How to apply theme to windows forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to know how can I apply theme to c# windows forms ?
or how can I enhance GUI without using WPF ?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Devexpress has some skins you can apply to winforms](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Skins/).